# nvidia compatibility list (more specific: Geforce GT 740)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

This is my first time trying to configure a PC which runs Ubuntu and a nvidia graphic card (more specific: The *Geforce GT 740*). I found the following link:

[Nvidia Official driver results](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/114708/en-us)

When clicking on "Supported products" there is a long list of nvidia cards.

**Question:**

If a nvidia graphics card (such as *Geforce GT 740*) is included in this list does that mean that the card will most likely run with Ubuntu?

Comment: You are better of checking phoronix. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=evga_geforce_gt740&num=3 The list from nVidia will only show products they would like to sell to you. Older hardware will still be just as good; but at a fraction of the price.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely. If you want to be sure you need to verify that the GPU is supported by a driver that is compatible with the kernel and X.org version of the Ubuntu release that you intend to run.

You can look for all Nvidia drivers that are supported in various Ubuntu releases on https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia.

If no combination of Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu releases works in your case you can always use the open-source Nouveau graphics driver albeit with a big performance hit.